# JSON API result format

Tags: node.js, json

Designing my first API in Node.JS using restify.js.  My background is not web APIs, pardon my amateur questions.  In any case, I would like to have the  `res.send(data);` responses to comply with the http://jsonapi.org/format/ so that my mobile application can start utilizing the API calls.  At the moment if you were to call my API, it would return data in the following format:

> {"Count":1,"Items":[{"dbsource":{"S":"foo"},"id":{"S":"5002820"},"name":{"S":"fnameblah,lnameblah"},"expiration":{"S":"06/13/2015"},"type":{"S":"bar"}}]}

Actually what you see above is just a return of a DynamoDB Query call.

So the question is... do you use a special library that you can pass data to, which would format and return the data in JSON format.  Which in turn you can return it via `res.send(data)` to the clients, or is it up to us to make 'data' JSON compliant, then return it?  At the end of the day we all want the results to look like:

```
{
  "posts": [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Rails is Omakase",
    "links": {
      "author": "9",
      "comments": [ "5", "12", "17", "20" ]
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In server side, stringify JSON object,

```
//...
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify(data)); //data is JSON object
res.end();
```

In client side, parse JSON string accordingly.

EDIT: Corrected response content type.

Comment: Thank you, so... right now I see the data as one string.  Is that OK?  Its not formatted as pretty as the examples on jsonapi.org/format.  Here is what my output looks like now: http://pastebin.com/RM3qJLih

Comment: Format? You want indention for debug? Try `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is... do you use a special library that you can pass data to, which would format and return the data in JSON format. Which in turn you can return it via res.send(data) to the clients, or is it up to us to make 'data' JSON compliant, then return it? At the end of the day we all want the results to look like:

Most of the time, you will like to have the back-end to serve an already valid JSON, which is actually the most used content type on REST APIs.

If you are using Express.js, you can add the [responser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oY4d.png) npm package to generate standard responses.

It lets you choose any of the http status code as methods.

Turn this:

```
router.get('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'BAD_REQUEST',
    code: 400,
    message: 'Request is wrong!',
    success: false
  })
})
```

into this:

```
router.get('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send_badRequest('Request is wrong!')
})
```

And both of the above will generate **exactly** the same output.

**Tip**: if you're using typescript, it will even show you all the available methods.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

JSON data from server should be a JSON string

You have to parse it back the JSON format in client.

```
JSON.parse(string);  // return JSON object
```